# VSTS Agent issue - dotnet has stopped working

Tags: .net, powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines, agent

We have a VSTS Agent running on our environment to make a continuous integration. It was working fine on the last months.

Today, Windows Server 2012 R2 performed a `blue screen` and now it is not working anymore. The Service is running on the windows `services` list as usual but on the `VSTS` online it shows that the agent is `offline`. So, we decide to try to reconfigure the agent and when we try to run the command:

```
PS> .\config.cmd remove
```

on the poweshell, we got the error message:

[image]

I am not sure if it is a Windows problem or the an agent setup or even a `dotnet` setup. Any command I try to run such as:

```
 PS> .\config.cmd help
 PS> .\run.cmd
```

I got this same message. I have tried all these commands and without success.

How can I solve this problem? It was working fine but not it just stopped because of a `blue screen`.

Comment: Question is more appropriate for superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Does the agent with a different name with Hosted VS2017? And there is a similar issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/700 which may caused by OS.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT No, I think it is a OS problem. I have create the same thread on github vsts-agent, if you could see and comment about: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1127 Maybe I will have to prepare a new environment, but not sure yet

Comment: Ok, you can re-install the OS and check if the problem still exist or not.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Let me ask something, I do not have experience with powershell but using powershell DSC, is it possible to prepare the system, I mean, prepare the IIS with all websites/apppools we need, install .net, aspnet and configure it? I am thinking it is an oportunity to learn it and be prepared if it happen again. Thank you.